# What is inside a .lnk file? How does it work?

Tags: shell, file-extension

I noticed that windows does not show the size of folders, however the size of files. Creating a shortcut however seems to create a new folder by the looks, however it shows that it is actually a file, that just shares the same look as folders on the GUI.

After some quick research I found: [Is a .lnk file a symbolic link or a junction?](https://superuser.com/questions/615721/is-a-lnk-file-a-symbolic-link-or-a-junction)

Which seemed to confirm my first guess. There was also an answer suggesting to simply drag an .lnk file into a txt editor - I did so, but what disappointed as the txt inside the .lnk file was just not readable.

Now I am just curious, if there was a way to actually decypher the file and understand its inner workings. As much as I got thus far, it is just a simple reference to another file or folder. However considering its 2KB size, it seems to me being unexpectedly big.

So what is exactly in the file? How does the reference work? How does it open the file referenced and not the file itself, when selecting?

Comment: See this article [Wikipedia:Shortcut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortcut_(computing)). You may open that lnk file in hex editor to see the readable section.

Comment: A lnk file is a link to a data object which may be something other than a file. Developers don't normally access the file contents directly but use system functions to create, modify, and access information. I believe the contents are documented by Microsoft somewhere. There have been many versions of the file type over the years making direct access difficult. Windows Explorer recognizes the file type and acts according to the contents

Answer (score 1):

To understand "what exactly is in the file" take a look at the [MS-SHLLINK](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-shllink/16cb4ca1-9339-4d0c-a68d-bf1d6cc0f943#published-version) specification. Also, these files are to be opened with a *Hex Editor* not a *Text Editor*.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this would help but recently I've wanted to run the Network Troubleshooter in command line instead of running it manually when ever my wifi card jitters up. I managed to create a (lnk) shortcut of this troubleshooter in the Control Panel but I wanted to add a command to my .bat script. Here's what I did to look at that lnk file:

1. I used [HxD](https://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/) to take a look at what it runs. This is the what
   [the HxD exported data looks like](https://pastebin.com/x0NaFkFZ).
2. Using my n00b skills and converting this string [using this python script](https://pastebin.com/5GSRAvuj), I get [this info](https://pastebin.com/bN1J7QTx):

   Identify and repair network problems
   %windir%\system32\Rundll32.exe ndfapi,NdfRunDllDiagnoseIncident

I can now copypasta that second line in cmd or in a .bat script of your choice.

**To answer your question:**

To inspect a .lnk file:

1. Open the file with [HxD](https://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/), and save the data in a file.
2. Run this python script to read only the string characters from that data file.
3. Resulting output file from the python script displays information on what the .lnk does and which system files it access. For my example, the resulting output includes this command:

   %windir%\system32\Rundll32.exe ndfapi,NdfRunDllDiagnoseIncident

Comment: Parsing a binary file as UTF-8 text, is never right.

Comment: Uh, I am not a programmer and I am not an expert in this area. I am not sure what you mean by "parsing a binary file as UTF-8". I was going through the steps of understanding the output from HxD and the python script was only included to get to the information I was looking for from the .lnk file. I quite proud that my python script did it's job as a macro and output only readable text.
Furthermore, I answered the question. The question asks if one could "decipher the file and understand its inner workings". The answer is yes and steps are provided to do so with a python scrip to help.

Comment: It looks to me that doing this is not in anyway wrong. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15199675/reading-utf-8-strings-from-a-binary-file) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113270/how-to-read-unicode-utf-8-binary-file-line-by-line).
My defense and my conclusion is that: It is perfectly reasonable to read text from a binary file using a python script.

Comment: It's reasonable to parse a binary file as text if the file is made for that purpose. In This case it's not reasonable to read this kind of binary file as text; as it's never intended to be read as text.

Comment: 1) I answered the question explicitly how it was asked (decoding a .lnk file) and I got a result that was the OP was asking for. This seems to be what Stack Exchange is so critical about: explicity answering the questions asked.
2) If the process leads to more understanding and a valid result, I believe the process then is justified even if improper (to you).

Comment: 3) The process of reading/writing text (which we understand) from/to computer language files,
to the best of my understanding, is the pinnacle of programming. Now, perhaps I skipped out on the complete decoding of that binary code. But if I open up a file, and I find what I am looking for, and I test what I found to make sure it is what it is, I believe that that is enough.

Comment: Now you are free to dig deeper and if you have a more valid, complete answer, I would love to read it. But I fail to see how my answer is invalid (in answering the question asked by OP), and I fail to see why "parsing a binary file as utf-8 text, is never right" and how that relates to my answer being invalid or unhelpful.
I'll also be frank, I am not a programmer. And so if I have broken some kind of unspoken or spoken rule, I would love a reference to it as well so I can educate myself.

Comment: "`#ignore x90 and other read errors`" and do you why those errors occur? To suppress those you pass `errors='ignore'`, do you even know what that does? That's where inaccuracy lies, it ignores errors while decoding with UTF-8, not to mention you loose data for that.

"But if I open up a file, and I find what I am looking for, and I test what I found to make sure it is what it is, I believe that that is enough." and because of those errors, you didn't get exactly what you desired.

Comment: I have a question, why do insist on that `it is reasonable to read a binary file as text`? I see no logic behind this. If a binary file was to be read same as text, then why do you have different *modes* to read files?

Comment: First, your explanation is not proper (not on par of StackExchange) and doesn't cover a general case and no you didn't explain it explicitly. Second, it's not invalid to me only but to any programmer with sense.  The third point is referring to the script you wrote. LNK is not a language. It's a structured binary file dictated by its corresponding specification. Also that may be enough, if prior information was possible to infer but still it's not proper.